# ScopedValue appears is not immutable

Tags: java, java-20

I am experimenting with scoped values, oracle JDK 20 on windows and eclipse 2023-03.
From what I've read ScopedValues are supposed to be immutable, but they do not appear so in my test code

```
package demoJava20;

import jdk.incubator.concurrent.ScopedValue;
class User { String name; };
public class ExampleScopedValues {
 public final static ScopedValue<User> LOGGED_IN_USER = ScopedValue.newInstance();
    
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   User loggedInUser = new User(); loggedInUser.name = "ABC";
   ScopedValue.where(LOGGED_IN_USER, loggedInUser, () -> f1()); // value will be available through f1
 }

private static void f1() {
    User user = LOGGED_IN_USER.get();
    System.out.println("In f1 user = " + user.name);
    user.name = "DEF";
    f2();
}

private static void f2() {
    User user = LOGGED_IN_USER.get();
    System.out.println("In f2 user = " + user.name);
    }
}
```

On my machine this prints

In f1 user = ABC

In f2 user = DEF

This code looks like it successfully changes the value from ABC to DEF and f2 sees the changed value.

Is it just the object reference that is immutable ( by not having a set method ), not the object itself?

Comment: This seems like a self-answering/ed question.

Comment: You are confusing mutability of an object reference with mutability of the object it refers to.  If you took scoped values out of the equation, you could have `final User u = new User(...)` and then still mutate `u.name`.  Here, `final` applies to the reference, but the object can still have mutable state.  Same with scoped values.

Comment: I started to suspect as I wrote the question. wondering if this should be deleted.

Comment: Use `record User(String name) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `user` is immutable, but as you and @Brian Goetz noted, you can still mutate the property `name`.